# Laravel, putting different column values in one variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this table:

```
Friends

id | friendid

10 | 15
12 | 10
10 | 13
```

and i want to put all values (either from id or friendid columns) in one variable. is it posible?

i have this code:

```
$id = 10;

$id = DB::table('friends')->where('id',  $x)->orWhere('friendid', $x)->lists('friendid');
```

but this line of code only returns values from 'friendid' column and what i want is to store values from 'friendid' and 'id' columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a second argument to `lists`, which will give set the keys of the resulting array:

```php
$query = DB::table('friends')->where('id',  $x)->orWhere('friendid', $x);

$results = $query->lists('friendid', 'id);
```

If you want it all as values of a single array, use this:

```php
$query = DB::table('friends')->where('id',  $x)->orWhere('friendid', $x);

$ids = [];

foreach ($query->select('id', 'friendid')->get() as $record) {
    $ids[] = $record->id;
    $ids[] = $record->friendid;
}
```

Comment: as i try to return $results it gives me {"13":10,"10":15,"12":10}
what i need is [13,10,10,15,12,10] is it the same?